# Auto-Scale WPF TextBox/RichTextBox content to fit available space

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, scaling, layouttransform

I have the following problem:

I want to setup a RichTextBox that automatically can resize the content inside to fit maximum of the available space while not change the layout of the content (e.g. Font sizes, Indent, etc.).

I saw already many questions about scaling the content of a TextBox but all questions was related to some kind of zoom slider. What I want is to really calculate the scaling so that it automatically best-fit into the TextBox.

What I have established so far is a LayoutTransform inside the AdornerDecorator of the RichTextBox template that is wrapped inside a ScrollViewer so that I can trigger a code-behind method to calculate the Scaling.

Initially the RichTextBox should not Scale when all content fit into the ViewPort. As soon as there is a need to enable the vertical ScrollBar, I change the ScaleFactor.

This works pretty good as long as it not comes to TextWrapping (so that scaling of X and Y will not cause the Text to wrap at different positions and additionally change the height).
Any ideas?

I created a small demo to make things a little bit more clearer:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ScaleTransform x:Key="ScaleTransform" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"
                                           ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox AcceptsTab="True" 
                 Background="Transparent" 
                 BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <RichTextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
                        <AdornerDecorator x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False"
                                          LayoutTransform="{StaticResource ScaleTransform}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </RichTextBox.Template>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private double scaleFactor = 1.0;
    public double ScaleFactor
    {
        get { return scaleFactor; }
        set
        {
            scaleFactor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScaleFactor");
        }
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExtentHeightChange == 0)
            return;

        if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(RichTextBox))
            return;

        var missingHeight = e.ExtentHeightChange;
        var heightWithoutScaling = e.ExtentHeight / ScaleFactor;

        if (e.ViewportHeight <= heightWithoutScaling)
        {
            ScaleFactor = ((e.ViewportHeight / heightWithoutScaling));
        }

    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to support what you want with text wrapping enabled. Because text wrapping introduce quite a complex problem. E.g. should we wrap text and then enlarge it, or should we not wrap it and make text smaller to fit by with. But there is a good chance, that if we wrap text, then height of the text will become bigger and will not fit. This is quite complex layout problem. Though, if you just disable text wrapping, it should work farely well, as you pointed yourself already. The only workaround is to create your own 100% custom layout algorithm for this.

Comment: Yes, with this you are totally right. Indeed, a complex layout problem. I experimented already in many ways with my code-behind so that I was able to create a deterministic approach by saving previous Scale/ExtentHeight, so that the method is not triggered forever. Anyway the result is absolutely not optimal. Hope to get some fresh ideas from here.